# SQL: query that fetches the rows ordered by the value of a column and fetches first the rows with a concret value in that column

Tags: sql

I want to do a query that fetchs the rows ordered by the value of a column and in the same time i want it fetches *first* the rows that has a concret value in that column.

For example:

```
it
es
fr
it
es
fr
```

If i want to show the rows with "es" first of all, the result would be:

```
es
es
it
it
fr
fr
```

Regards

Javi

Comment: Please give an example of your data and an example of the desired result.  Then we can see what you are trying to do.

Comment: What exactly is the definition of "concrete" value? Not null?

Comment: @user248959, did the edited answer help you? If not, can you please tell us the error or problem you found? Thanks and best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing here you want to get first the records with 'es' in the column and afterwards the rest in ascendent order (in your example you are using descendent order).

If that is the case you can do it like this (in Oracle)

```
Select *
From
(
  Select T.*, 0 orden
    From Table T
   Where column_name= 'es'
   Union
  Select T.*, 1 orden
    From Table T
   Where column_name <> 'es'
)
Order By orden, column_name
```

To change the order direction for the column just put a Desc in the order by clause.

EDIT: for MySQL try instead

```
Select *
From
(
  Select T.*, 0 orden
    From Table AS T
   Where column_name= 'es'
   Union
  Select T.*, 1 orden
    From Table AS T
   Where column_name <> 'es'
)
Order By orden, column_name
```

I have no MySQL instance at hand now so I can not test it.

Best regards

Comment: that should be "union select (...) from table T where column_name != 'es'", shouldn't it? Otherwise your 'es'-rows get returned twice, once on top and once with all the other rows...

Comment: I have tried "select * from my_table where culture = 'es' UNION select * from sedi_i18n where culture <> 'es' order by culture" but i get this order: es es fr it fr it. Any idea?

Comment: @Guillem Vicens. I have tried what you say but this error appears SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Table T
Where culture= 'es'
Union
Select T.*, 1 orden
From Tab' at line 5

Comment: @Christian Severin, that would be the case if I had used UNION ALL, but I used UNION.

Comment: @user248959, sorry I answered before you specified your database. I tried this query in an Oracle instance. I'll edit the post for it

Comment: @Guillem Vicens: UNION removes duplicates, yes -- but the two sets of 'es'-rows aren't exactly the same: one set has orden = 1 and the other has orden = 0. I don't know how this works in mySQL, but in TSQL, UNION keeps both sets of 'es'-rows.

Comment: @Christian Severin, you're right, I forgot about the added column. I edited the post again to fix it. Thanks for your input. :-)